# PowerShell Test-Connection cmdlet shows successful ping for any name

Tags: powershell, networking

Why am I getting a successful ping for any provided computer name even though the computer doesn't exist in my network?

When I run the following:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName ak
```

It results in the following output:

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address       Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------       -----    --------
DESKTOP...    ak              some ip                            32       611
DESKTOP...    ak              some ip                            32       189
DESKTOP...    ak              some ip                            32       160
DESKTOP...    ak              some ip                            32       138
```

Comment: What the heck lol that's odd. What about IP's? Can you clear your DNS record and try again?

Comment: There could be a wildcard DNS entry at play here

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell as an administrator and try these commands and see if you can spot anything strange:

Check hosts file:

```
Get-Content "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Check You IP settings

```
IPCONFIG /All
```

Check your arp rable:

```
arp -a
```

Clear your DNS cache and try again:

```
IPCONFIG /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a network-local DNS server, you could have a wildcard (default) record where DNS requests not matching a host record will return a default record instead.

Alternatively, you can try going through the boilerplate troubleshooting options:

```
# Check that your hosts file hasn't been tampered with
Get-Content $env:SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

# Confirm IP, DNS, and route settings
Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily ipv4
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily ipv4
Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily ipv4

# Flush DNS
Clear-DnsClientCache

# Review arp
Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily ipv4
```

But diving into the results of these here will veer off topic, so if you find something amiss with the settings above I would recommend asking follow up questions at https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com.